# Many-to-one with formula in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following tables:

```
tableA: id[PK], name
tableB: id[PK], idTableA[FK], dateClosed
```

And my object model is the following:

```
class ObjectA {
    private Integer id:
    private String name;
    private ObjectB activeB;
}

class ObjectB {
    private Integer id;
    private ObjectA a;
    private Date dateClosed;
}
```

So the property **activeB** in **ObjectA** should be the one whose *dateClosed* is NULL (there can be only one ObjectB at the time with null *dateClosed*).

I'm stuck while writing the *many-to-one* relation with the correct formula to get the active **ObjectB**... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's actually a one-to-one relationship between A and B.

Below is Java EE 6; I don't know if there is much difference with hibernate.

```
@Entity    
class ObjectA {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id:
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a")
    private ObjectB activeB;
}

@Entity
class ObjectB {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idTableA")
    private ObjectA a;
    private Date dateClosed;
}
```

As far as having a single B with null value, my guess is that it cannot be implemented in a database.  So you would need the rest of your code (non-relational) to take care of this aspect.